# Nginx Config for Camunda Webapp

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, camunda

I am configuring camunda webapp with nginx reverse proxy. Applications is loading perfectly fine using location / (Root Path). But I need to access it using a readable location path e.g. /process/. I tried a lot with several rewrites and redirections but to no success. 
At root path all the static content loads but with other location path it fails. I'm a newbie in Nginx So it would make complete sense if i'm missing something very trivial.

Here is my config with location as Root Path:

```
server {

  listen 8080;
  server_name abc.xyz.net;
  rewrite_log on;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log notice;

  location / {

    # Simple requests
    if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST)") {

      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
    }

    # Preflighted requests
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {

      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
      return 200;
    }

    proxy_pass http://camunda-webapp.xyz.net;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_read_timeout 180s;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

On another context, If I try to give full URL in proxy_pass(Refer below config) then it works but the browser URL gets completely changed to proxy_pass URL.(I had even tried with proxy_redirect to retain the original URL but it doesn't work)

```
server {

  listen 8080;
  server_name abc.xyz.net;
  rewrite_log on;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log notice;

  location /process/ {
  rewrite ^\/(?>[process]+)(\/.*) $1 break;

    # Simple requests
    if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST)") {

      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
    }

    # Preflighted requests
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {

      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
      return 200;
    }

    proxy_pass http://camunda-webapp.xyz.net/app/welcome/default;
    proxy_redirect http://camunda-webapp.xyz.net/app/welcome/default https://abc.xyz.net/process

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host/process;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_read_timeout 180s;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

Any kind of info or help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.
Bella Ciao!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the trick is to specify the same **location context** of the nginx as the **context path** of the your application.

Also, please remove url rewrite as its not needed here.